# Uninstall correct instance of node_modules

Tags: linux, npm, node-modules

Newbie here.

I have two instances of node_modules in linux/Ubuntu:
1.  Root
2.  Usr/local/lib
How do I determine which one to uninstall?
How do uninstall?

You're help is sincerely appreciate.
LV

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/uninstalling-global-packages might help.

Comment: Thanks I will look at this.